# Permutations: Show that the sign of a 2-cycle is -1

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

I'm supposed to show that the sign of a 2-cycle is -1, and I'm not allowed to use the formula: $\text{sign}(f) = (-1)^l$ (where $l$ describes the number of 2-cycles that compose the permutation $f$)

I'm not quite sure how to do this generally. My plan was to use the formula $\text{sign}(f)= f(F_n)/F_n$, and then compute $f(F_n)$ and $F_n$ generally by saying that $f = (ab)$. But it ended up getting rather confusing, so I'm not sure whether that's the way to go.

Comment: What is $Fn$? And what is meant by the division of permutations in this context?

Comment: See this:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation

Comment: Well, it depends on what's your definition of sign of a permutation $\sigma$. Sometimes it's defined in the following way: -1 if you need an odd number of 2-cycles to compose with $\sigma$ in order to obtain the identity; 1 if you need an even number of 2-cycles. (Clearly one has to verify that this is a well definition). Now, since the inverse of a 2-cycle is still a 2-cycles, you get, according with the definition, that the sign of a 2-cycles is $-1$.

Comment: Fn is the polynomial which is also shown in the wiki link - they just call it P(x1,...,xn) - I think the link helped a little in proof 2 :)

Answer (score 2):

The sign of a permutation is $-1$ raised to the number of inversions in that permutation. What do we mean by inversion? If $i<j$ but $\sigma (i) > \sigma(j)$, then the pair $(i,j)$ is called an inversion. Your permutation looke like

$$\left( \begin{array} {ccccccccccc} 1 & \dots & i-1 & \color{red}i & i+1 & \dots & j-1 & \color{red}j & j+1 & \dots & n \\ 1 & \dots & i-1 & \color{red}j & i+1 & \dots & j-1 & \color{red}i & j+1 & \dots & n \end{array} \right) .$$

Let us count the inversions.

Note that all the pairs $(k,l)$ with $1 \le k \le i-1$ and $k < l$ are *not* inversions.

Next, investigate the pairs $(i,l)$ with $i < l$: they will be inversions iff $i+1 \le l \le j$, which gives $j-i$ inversions so far.

Now, the pairs $(k,l)$ with $i+1 \le k \le j-1$ and $k < l$ are inversions only when $l = j$, and this gives $j-i-1$ more inversions.

Finally, none of the pairs $(k, l)$ with $j \le k$ and $k < l$ is an inversion.

Adding them all, you get a total of $2(j-i) - 1$ inversions, which is an odd number, so the sign is $(-1) ^{\big( 2(j-i) - 1 \big)} = -1$.

Comment: Thank you - this was very helpful :)